# how to add barbutton item in tab bar programmaticaly in iphone

Tags: iphone

here in my application i want to add barbuttonitem in tab bar.

i displayed tab bar in view but i dont no how to add barbuttonitem programmaticaly in iphone.

can any one plz give me information about my problem.

thank you in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not add bar button items to tab bar.

To add bar button item to a toolbar

//Create a BarButtonItem configure the way you want.

```
self.forwardButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay
                          target:nil action:nil];
```

// Create an array for all the bar buttons

```
NSArray *toolBarItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:forwardButton,nil];
```

// Set toolar items

```
[self.toolBar setItems:toolBarItems];
```

// add items to toolbar

```
[self addSubview:self.toolBar];
```

**EDIT**

In case you want to add space between BarButtonItems

```
UIBarButtonItem *spaceItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add barbuttonitem in tab bar. You can add barbuttonitem in tool bar. for that check out this link

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/59285-programmatically-add-button-uitoolbar.html